# Update if one of the values exist, else insert

Tags: mysql, if-statement

How can I at an insert query, check if a specific column has a specific value and then update the row. Otherwise it should insert a new row.

Somethings like this is what I want:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3) UPDATE IF col3 = $number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `UNIQUE` key over your `col3`:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD UNIQUE KEY (col3)
```

Then use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = VALUES(col1), col2 = VALUES(col2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `REPLACE INTO` command ([MySQL docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)).

```
REPLACE INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3);
```

It checks primary keys and unique indexes and when there is a matching entry already present, that row is replaced by the new one, else a new row is inserted.

**EDIT**

As @eggyal mentioned this the behaviour in the case, when the row is replaced, is actually a deletion of the old row and insertion of the new row afterwards. This may lead to some problems, when you're using triggers, foreign keys or alike.

Actually you might loose the content of some columns as well. Suppose you have a table with 3 columns (`col1` to `col3`), but the `REPLACE` just sets two of them (`col1`, `col2`), the third one `col3` will receive the default value specified and not retain the old value.

Comment: Thanks! Works great! :) Though isn't REPLACE INTO a performance problem?

Comment: `REPLACE` doesn't "update" the record, it deletes the existing one and inserts a new one.  Subtle difference, but worth noting where some columns are left to their default values or where triggers may result in unexpected outcomes.

Comment: @eggyal Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: It's not just when using triggers etc: if the `REPLACE` doesn't explicitly set every column, then whatever data was in those columns will be lost when the original record is deleted and replaced with default values when the new record is inserted.  That's the biggest difference between `REPLACE` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

if you have unique index on that column then use this

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col3 = $number
```